# .htaccess error when url doesn't end with /

Tags: .htaccess

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js|wiff|woff2|ttf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Example of working urls

```
http://www.website.com/u/johndoe/asdf
http://www.website.com/u/johndoe/
```

Unique Error

```
http://www.website.com/u/johndoe
```

In the unique error case, the url is changed to:

```
http://www.website.com/u/johndoe/?path=u/johndoe
```

does anyone know why the ?path=u is being adding to the url?
It is physically in the url field at the top of the browser.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: Nope, that is all there is.

Comment: NOTE: there are no files or directories called u.

This problem doesn't happen if you change it to any other letter.